# Repeating "some" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I have the following sentence

> the user specifies **some** anchors by selecting **some** elements of the page.

Is it an alternative to avoid repeating "some"?

Comment: "Some" is not informative and is unnecessary. "By selecting elements on the page, the user is (indirectly) specifying anchors."  Does the user know about anchors, or are anchors  "behind the scenes", an implementation detail of which the user is unaware?

Comment: @TRomano user knows about anchors, After selecting an element by mouse, right clicks and in a context-menu selects "Create Anchor"....

Answer (score 2):

You can always avoid repetition by searching synonyms. If you're talking about a *small quantity* here, synonyms for *some* are *a few*, *several*,...
Just be careful that introducing the synonym does not alter the meaning of the sentence.

In your case you could say, for example:

> - The user specifies **several** anchors by selecting **some** elements of the page.
> - The user specifies **some** anchors by selecting **a few** elements of the page.

Comment: Good, however you know they are corresponded! I mean for each anchor an element is needed, then I wasn't sure how to convey this correspondence. The first sentence seems promising.

Comment: The act of *specifying ... anchors* is already linked to *selecting ... elements* through the use of the word **by**. The words *some, several, a few* only modify the **amount** of the noun that they refer to.